# Get all children of the work item with WIQL

Tags: azure-devops, wiql

I have Azure DevOps work items (user stories and bugs), which are linked to epic work item called "Version 1" (Id 137).

Is it possible to retrieve **only** the children of this epic with Wiql?

Comment: Implementing this with query is also fine, but the top level entry (epic) needs to be filtered out somehow.